# Openshift route whitelist gives 502 bad gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift, haproxy, okd

We have an okd 3.11 cluster running on AWS. When creating a route with the ip_whitelist annotation, i get '502 bad gateway'. Same YAML definition works fine on our old on prem cluster with openshift 3.6

Any hints for me?

Comment: What's the exact annotation you're using? Perhaps it's changed on 3.11? Or you could be using a different router backend? The default is HAProxy, but it's pluggable to other backend.

Comment: `haproxy.router.openshift.io/ip_whitelist: 80.XX.XX.XX/32`

I double checked that the option hasn't changed and the HAProxy is in place.
I think the problem is related to the AWS LB in the chain.